# `boost` `bootstrap.bat` doesn't work with Visual Studio 2015/Windows 7 x64

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015

I try to build boost 1.61 with Visual Studio 2015 and Windows 7 x64. As always I run `bootstrap.bat` with Visual Studio 2015 native x64 command prompt. However, I see following message box:

`Unsupported 16-Bit application`

`The program of feature jam0.exe can not start or run due to incompatibity with 64-bit versions of Windows`

How to fix this issue?

Comment: The error pretty much says it all. Get a version that is compatible with 64-bit systems or run it from a 32-bit OS.

Comment: I don't think this error is normal one; why x64 boost depend on 16-bit code?

Comment: Why not use 1.61 boost ? https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.61.0/

Comment: It is spelling error; yes, I use latest boost, for now it is 1.61, I just downloaded it hour ago.